# Почему не отправляются данные с формы?

Tags: html, django, post, html-form

Есть следующая HTML-форма:

```html
<form id="reg" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/rais/login/" method="POST">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter your Email" required>
        <!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your email</small> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPass">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPass" placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
        <!-- <small id="passHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter your password</small> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <label class="form-check-label">
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
          Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center form">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Log in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Запросы принимает сервер на Django. При нажатии на кнопку приходит POST-запрос, как и ожидалось, однако его `request.POST` пуст. Также при нажатии F12 и переходе в Network при просмотре отправленных заголовков отсутствует заголовок `Form Data`, хотя при отправке самой просто формы по первой ссылке из Google данный заголовок присутствует и содержит отправляемые данные.

Вопрос: что не так с данной формой, как сделать, чтобы она отправляла данные вместе с POST-запросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для всех `input` задайте атрибут `name`

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это сработало. Глупейшая ошибка, обоснованная крайне малым опытом работы с HTML.